# Site está exibindo posts do dia 2 de maio, porém, alguns acessam as notícias atualizadas normalmente

Tags: wordpress, navegador-de-internet, conexão, hospedagem

Administro o site www.atodahora.com.br - Desde o dia 7 de maio, às 12h, no meu escritório, visualizo ele como se a data fosse 2 de maio. Não vejo nada além disso. Isso ocorre com outras conexões. Acontece que em outros locais, boa parte das pessoas visualizam o site como deixei pela última vez. No dia 2 de maio, a notícia de destaque é sobre o SAMU. já no dia 7, é sobre o Rio Claro FC. Fiz os procedimentos de limpeza de cache e redirecionamento de DNS na minha conexão, mas nada, não atualiza. Outro exemplo é que quem acessa o dia 7 normalmente, quando tenta pelo Edge, acessa o do SAMU e a notícia do Rio Claro dá erro 404. Não consigo achar se o problema é do servidor de internet, hospedagem ou mesmo no Wordpress. Alguém já enfrentou esse tipo de situação?

[image: Dia 2 de maio]
[[image: Dia 7 de maio[2]]

Comment: O que eu percebi é que seu site muda de acordo com ter `www` ou não. Isso pode dar uma pista de onde procurar o problema. Muito provavelmente são dois WP com dados diferentes. Fez alguma migração recente? Além disso, seus DNSs estão fora de sincronismo, então está acontecendo um "sorteio" de quem vai ver o que. O DNS sozinho não seria capaz de mudar os conteúdos. O fato de ter dois servidores sim.

Comment: Seus registros A apontam para estes endereços 174.142.214.201 e 173.193.195.155, cada um está mostrando um conteúdo. Isto é um problema ou de configuração errada, ou se for proposital, falta de sincronismo nos 2 servidores.

Answer (score 0):

No seu DNS

Coloque o sem www com o IP do conteudo mais actual

```
A @ IP
```

o www coloque antes assim

```
CNAME www atodahora.com.br
```

Isto faz com que o www.atodahora.com.br seja um alias do atodahora.com.br